# How to delete a deleted project from Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, project, manual

I have deleted a project folder with filesystem utilities, but it is still listed in a project explorer of Eclipse Helios. How to delete project from there too?

Deletion from .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects does not help (i.e. folders are deleted from there too, but listed in project explorer nevertheless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to "refresh" project explorer. Not sure if it is required to delete folders first, but after it was done and after refresh, Eclipse explicitly asked to remove absent projects.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just right click in the project explorer and select delete?

In future, use the Eclipse option to delete projects (it also gives you the option of deleting from the file system or not).

Comment: There is no Delete option in rightclick menu, so I can't delete this project this way too. The project is in "closed" state. So I neither can delete it, nor open. Also I can't create new project with the same name, because Eclipse sure it exists. Very uncomfortable bug!

Comment: double click on the project or either right click first open the project then again do right click then the delete option will come...

Answer (score 0):

The problem can arise when you have deleted a project, but did not click the "delete project contents on disk(cannot be undone)". The project exists in a kind of limbo.
If you get errors reported on this project, then in the "Problems" tab click on the "Resources" line and "Show in.." project explorer. Now you can really delete it.